# Order of results in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have two questions about query results in Cassandra.

1. When I make a "full" select of a table in Cassandra (ie. `select * from table`) is it *guaranteed* that the results will be returned in increasing order of partition tokens?
   For instance, having the following table:

   ```
   create table users(id int, name text, primary key(id));
   ```

   Is it guaranteed that the following query will return the results with increasing values in the token column?

   ```
   select token(id), id from users;
   ```

   If so, is it also guaranteed if the data is distributed to multiple nodes in the cluster?
2. If the anwer to the above question is 'yes', is it still valid if we use secondary index? For instance, if we would have the following index:

   ```
   create index on users(name);
   ```

   and we query the table by using the index:

   ```
   select token(id), id from users where name = 'xyz';
   ```

   is there any guarantee regarding the order of results?

The motivation for the above questions is if the token is the right thing to use in order in implement paging and/or resuming of broken longer "data exports".

EDIT: There are multiple resources on the net that state that the order matches the token order (eg. in description of [partitioner results](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) or [this Datastax page](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order)):

> Without a partition key specified in the WHERE clause, the actual order of the result set then becomes dependent on the hashed values of userid.

However the order of results is not specified in official Cassandra documentation, eg. of [SELECT statement](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#select).

Answer (score 3):

> Is it guaranteed that the following query will return the results with increasing values in the token column?

Yes it is

> If so, is it also guaranteed if the data is distributed to multiple nodes in the cluster?

The data distribution is orthogonal to the ordering of the retrieved data, no relationship

> If the anwer to the above question is 'yes', is it still valid if we use secondary index?

Yes, even if you query data using a secondary index (be it SASI or the native implementation), the returned results will always be sorted by token order. Why ? The technical explanation is given in my blog post here: http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=13191#cluster_read_path

That's the main reason that explain why SASI is not a good fit if you want the search to return data ordered by some column values. Only a real search engine integration (like Datastax Enterprise Search) can yield you the correct ordering because it bypasses the cluster read path layer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But is there any reason why this guarantee is not mentioned in official documentation, eg. the one of SELECT query which I mentioned?

Comment: Because 1) with Cassandra, the best practices recommend to use SELECT on a single partition --> rows sorted by clustering columns values and 2) Range queries like SELECT using 2nd index or without partition key are generally not recommended and 3) the ordering by token value is true only when using Random or Murmur3 partitioners. When using ByteOrderedPartitioner the rows are ordered by partition keys